# How do I know that this sequence exists in the vector space?

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $(V_i, \|\cdot \|_i), i=1,2$ be normed vector spaces over $\mathbb{F}$ and let $T$ be a linear map from $V_1 \to V_2$, and assume that $T$ is not bounded.

How do I know that there exists a seq. $(x_n)_n \in V_1$ s.t $\|x_n\| \leq 1$ and $\|Tx_n \| \geq n$ $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$?

I know that by def of bounded linear operator we have $\|T\| = \sup_{x \in V_1, \|x\| \leq 1} \|Tx\|_{V_1}$ but since $T$ is not bounded, this must fail. But why do we have $\geq n$?

The claim is made in the solution in a problem Im working on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"$T$ is bounded" means "There exists an $n\in \Bbb N$ (really $\in \Bbb R^+$, but it is the same in the end) such that for any $x\in V_1$ with $\|x\|\leq 1$, we have $\|Tx\|\leq n$".

If you negate that definition, you get that "$T$ is not bounded" means "For any $n\in \Bbb N$ there is an $x\in V_1$ with $\|x\|\leq 1$ such that $\|Tx\|\not\leq n$".